# Zurb Foundation equalised grid: how to position content at bottom of div inside grid cell

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

There are many questions about how to position content at the bottom of a `div`, and usually it's not too hard to do nowadays with Flexbox.

However, I'm using the Zurb Foundation grid with equalisation. The equalisation is necessary because my `cell`s contain an image (fixed height) and a caption - which is variable length.

The caption includes a title (sitting directly under the image), and a subtitle, which I want to sit at the bottom of the image card.

Here's a Codepen showing what I'm working with: https://codepen.io/arokat/pen/ZEbzOMp

I've tried a lot of suggested solutions (flexbox, setting `height: 100%` on the `.image-card-caption__title`, etc), but I just can't get the subtitle to stick to the bottom + get the right overall appearance. (Setting absolute positioning + `bottom: 0` throws off the whole layout ...)

I think the problem is that the height of the div isn't set until after the JS equalisation code is run - so any CSS rules are applied at the wrong time.

I'd really like to avoid setting a fixed height on the `.image-card-caption` div, since both the title & subtitle could vary in length quite a lot.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance :)

How it looks currently:
[image: How it looks currently]

How I want it to look:
*(approximated - the alignment isn't perfect, I just did that with `<br />` tags to give the idea)*
[image: How I want it to look]

Comment: Quick question, do you require for the images to be used as images or that's irrelevant?

Comment: I mean to say, is there a problem that the images are handled as backgrounds of a container or your requirements specify you need an image?

Comment: Hi @MihailMinkov, yes, they should be images set via the `<image>` tag, rather than than in the CSS via `background-image`. The reasons is that they're search results. I can use `background-image` if absolutely necessary, but it would be preferable to avoid it!

Comment: Check my answer below. Perhaps some absolute positioning of the images inside the container could do the trick.

Comment: Also, never forget to use `<div class="grid-container">` haha

Comment: Good point - updated the Codepen to wrap it in `.grid-container`!

Comment: However, it's really not the images that are the issue here, it's about the caption positioning ...

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and did something really similar to what you have with certain code modifications that use either Foundation components that improve and simplify the structure or "hacks" that help achieve what you need.

You can check it [on this CodePen](https://codepen.io/mi_ov/pen/pojzEww)

Let me explain what I did.

1. When you are using a grid layout, Foundation has the option for you to make [Block Grids](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#block-grids). It's really simple and really easy to use and solves you the need to calculate how many columns must each breakpoint have. What I did was

```html
<div class='grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3'>
```

What this does is that it indicates to the container that it will have 1 block per-row on small devices, 2 blocks per-row on medium devices, and 3 blocks per-row on large devices and above. All you have to do after that is just define a cell like this:

```html
<div class='cell'>
```

As you can see, this is much easier than `<div class='cell medium-6 large-4'>` and it saves a lot of typing.

2. I specifically asked you above if you require to use the images in the `img` tag. Why? I like to use a transparent spacer with this `svg` element. It's really light.

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1'%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

What this does is that it creates a 1x1 SVG image, but since it doesn't have a specific width and height it just has a viewBox with a proportion 1:1 which is basically a square. That way it occupies the available space and creates a responsive square shape. Since it's transparent you can use the original image as a background of the parent element.

This way your `.image-card__image` element will always have the same proportion in each `.image-card` element, thus allowing you to use `data-equalizer` specifically for the titles.

3. Data-equalizer can actually be used on multiple elements, syncing multiple heights, but the structure in this case does not really require that. What I did was basically name the `data-equalizer` to `title` (you can check more on that [here](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/equalizer.html#nesting)) and I assigned the `data-equalizer-watch='title'` parameters to the title container elements.

Also, I didn't use the flex definitions you had for `.image-card__image`. Using the SVG they are not really necessary.

Do those changes work for you?

Comment: Adding the data-equaliser onto the title was the perfect solution. Thank you SO much @MihailMinkov!

Comment: I didn't yet change the images to the SVG wrapper, but I will look into this as well. Again, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)